# How is multiplication in field $GF(2^{8})$ done?

Tags: aes

I am working on AES and I am stuck on multiplication in $GF(2^{8})$ field.

In terms of polynomial it is easy; I just have to multiply polynomials modulo $(x^{8} + x^{4} + x^{3} + x + 1)$. But I do not understand multiplication with $x$, following an example given in NIST specification:

> {57} • {13} = {fe}

solution:

> {57} • {02} = xtime({57}) = {ae}
>   {57} • {04} = xtime({ae}) = {47}
>   {57} • {08} = xtime({47}) = {8e}
>   {57} • {10} = xtime({8e}) = {07},

thus

> {57} • {13} = {57} • ({01} $XOR$ {02} $XOR$ {10})
>    = {57} $XOR$ {ae} $XOR$ {07}
>   = {fe}

I am unable to understand a single step in this, please also explain the `x_time()` function too.

Also, how is $x^{i}$ calculated? I need this for the $rcon[i]$ matrix.

**Edit:** this question has been marked as a possible duplicate of [Understanding multiplication in the AES specification](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14902/understanding-multiplication-in-the-aes-specification). I have already read this but the explanation is not sufficient, I am unable to understand the concept hence I have posted this question, because I need a somewhat detailed answer.Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding multiplication in the AES specification](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14902/understanding-multiplication-in-the-aes-specification)

Comment: @kodlu I've checked this already, the answer you mentioned. But it didn't solved the problem, I can't understand the given explanation. Hence, I posted this question here.

Comment: To clarify: when you say `I am unable to understand a single step in this, please also explain the x_time() function too.` – do you mean you have general problems with the basic math used there and expect answers to go though it step-by-step, or are you just having problems understanding what `x_time()` means/does?

Comment: @e-sushi, I'm having problems with both, I can implement x_time() just by it's definition but the question I mentioned in the post, I can't understand the steps, e.g. `{57} • {13} = {57} • {13} = {57} • ({01} 
XOR
XOR
{02} 
XOR
XOR
{10})` how this is inferred from the steps above it.

Answer (score 9):

Consider we want to obtain $\mathtt{0x57} \cdot \mathtt{0x02}$. First we see this one by polynomial method
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}\tag{3}
\mathtt{0x57} \cdot \mathtt{0x02}&=&(01010111)_2 \cdot (00000010)_2\\
&=&({x}^{6}+{x}^{4}+{x}^{2}+x+1)\cdot x\\
&=&{x}^{7}+{x}^{5}+{x}^{3}+x^2+x \\
&=& (10101110)_2\\
&=& \mathtt{0xAE}
\end{array}
$$
The relation $(3)$ means that when an element of $\alpha \in\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$ multiplied by an element $\mathtt{0x02}$ we shift the binary mode of $\alpha$ in the left side.

Now, if the first bit (from left) of $\alpha$ is  $1$ we should $\operatorname{XOR}$ the results with $\mathtt{0x1B}= (00011011)_2$ since when the first bit is  $1$, it means we have $x^7$ in the representation of $\alpha$ and by multiplying by $x$ we get $x^8$ and we use the polynomial $x^4+x^3+x+1$ instead of $x^8$ in our calculation.

We call this operation `x_time()`. For instance, let we want to get $\mathtt{0x57} \cdot \mathtt{0x04}$. The element $\mathtt{0x04}=(00000100)_2$ is equal to $x^2$. Therefor to obtain $\mathtt{0x57} \cdot \mathtt{0x04}$ we use the function `x_time()` two times. In $(3)$ we got $\mathtt{0x57} \cdot \mathtt{0x02}=\mathtt{0xAE}$.

In the rest, to obtain $\mathtt{0xAE} \cdot \mathtt{0x02}$, first we shift the binary mode of $\mathtt{0xAE}=(10101110)_2$ in the left side that implying that $$
(10101110)_2 \stackrel{shift\, to\, left}{\Longrightarrow} (01011100)_2 \tag{4}
$$ 
The first bit of $\mathtt{0xAE}=(10101110)_2$ is $1$ and hence we $\operatorname{XOR}$ the result obtained in $(4)$, with $(00011011)_2$ as follows 
$$
 (01011100)_2 \quad \operatorname{XOR}\quad (00011011)_2=(01000111)_2=71=\mathtt{0x47}
$$
I suggest you to obtain other cases as an exercise.

Comment: Actually I got the mathematical part, I mentioned this in the post. I was having trouble with the xor implementation, I am writing code for AES so I want to understand the xor implementation. Please explain that if you can, I'll be grateful for that. Thanks

Comment: @Nilesh When I wanted to implement AES I used Lookup-table method. Recently, I saw [this vedio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSXIuoVzcxo) that the author has said in the last slide "Forget the finite field". You can see his article [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1151.pdf). I mean, if you want to start the implementation of AES, I strongly recommended to learn the  heuristics algorithm to construct lightweight MDS matrices without using XOR. Please be curious to find better results([here](https://github.com/pfasante/shorter_linear_slps_for_mds_matrices))