# How are m2 and m3 boxes computed?

Tags: aes

I stumbled upon an AES implementation that uses boxes with multiples of 2 and 3 for its MixColumns operation. When inspecting the m2 box, I saw that the first line is :

```
0x00,0x02,0x04,0x06,0x08,0x0A,0x0C,0x0E,0x10,0x12,0x14,0x16,0x18,0x1A,0x1C,0x1E,
```

So nothing abnormal, but once we reach 0xFE, the next line is :

```
0x1B,0x19,0x1F,0x1D,0x13,0x11,0x17,0x15,0x0B,0x09,0x0F,0x0D,0x03,0x01,0x07,0x05,
```

Why does it become so weird ? How were those boxes computed ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AES mixcolumn stage](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12873/aes-mixcolumn-stage) and [Understanding multiplication in the AES specification](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14902/18298) and [How are these AES MixColumn multiplication tables calculated?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/71204/18298)

Answer (score 1):

A byte $b$ in AES represents a polyonmial of degree at most $7$ where the coefficients are the bits of $b$. An example is the byte written in hexadecimal `f3` represents $x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x + 1$ (with big endian order).

There are two operations with these polynomials: the addition and the multiplication. Given the polynomials $f(x) = a_7 x^7 + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$ and $g(x) = b_7x^7 + \cdots + b_1 x + b_0$, then the addition is
$$
f(x) + g(x) = (a_7 \oplus b_7) x^7 + \cdots + (a_1 \oplus b_1) x + (a_0 \oplus b_0),
$$
using a `xor` between the coefficients of each polynomial, so the resulting polynomial is also of degree at most $7$, with binary coefficients.
Concerning the multiplication it is necessary to add a reduction in case the degree of the polynomial is greater than $7$. Example:
$$
f(x) \cdot x = a_7 x^8 + \cdots + a_1 x^2 + a_0 x.
$$
In particular for AES, it is a modular reduction with the polynomial $h(x) = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$. It means that in all the calculcations, we have
$$
x^8 = x^4 + x^3 + x + 1,
$$
so the previous calculation becomes
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
f(x) \cdot x & = & a_7(x^4 + x^3 + x + 1) + a_6 x^7 + \cdots + a_1 x^2 + x \\
 & = & a_6 x^7 + a_5 x^6 + a_4 x^5 + (a_7 \oplus a_3) x^4 + (a_7 \oplus a_2) x^3 \\
& & + a_1 x^2 + (a_7 \oplus a_0) x + a_7
\end{array}
$$
Why in particular this polynomial $h(x)$ is because it has degree $8$ and cannot be written as a product of two (or more) non-trivial polynomials (similar as prime numbers that cannot be written as the product of two or more integers greater than $1$).

Now, all that is said above is enough to understand the `m2` and `m3` boxes that can be encountered in some implementations. The `m2` box is only the multiplication by $x$ of all polynomials. For polynomials of degree at most $6$, it means only a bitwise shift left, but for polynomials of degree $7$, a reduction is necessary.
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\hline
\text{hex} & \text{polynomial} &  \text{times } x & \text{hex}\\
\hline
\texttt{00} & 0 & 0 \cdot x = 0 & \texttt{00}\\
\texttt{01} & 1 & 1 \cdot x = x & \texttt{02}\\
\vdots \\
\texttt{7F} & x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 & x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x & \texttt{FE} \\
\texttt{80} & x^7 & x^7 \cdot x = x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 & \texttt{1b} \\
\vdots \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
The `m3` box is the multiplication by $x + 1$ and is easily obtained with an addition of the polynonmial $f$ with the result of the `m2` box since:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) \cdot (x + 1) & = f(x) \cdot x + f(x) \cdot 1 \\
& = f(x) \cdot x + f(x)
\end{align}
$$

More information on the [wikipedia page of finite fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) for a more general description finite fields.